# expressjs get request error 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I recently started working with expressjs. now i have a problem with my routing in get requests.
this is my app.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    var login=require('./routes/login');//get a js file login.js
    app.use('/user_form',login);
```

in the loginjs i have two requests:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
 var urlencodedParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

    router.post("/", function (req,res,next) {
    var sess = req.session;
    var answer = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    if (users[answer.username] && users[answer.username].password == 
    answer.password) {
        users[answer.username].logged = true;
        sess.logged = answer.username;
        res.redirect("/");
    }
    else {
        res.render("fail");
    }
    });

    router.get("/logged", function (req, res) {
    sess = req.session;
    res.send(sess.logged);
    });
```

the post one works but the get one doesn't , it always gives me error 500 and i cannot figure out the problem.

this is the code in the client side :

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "user_form/logged",
    dataType: "xml"
  }).done(function (res) {
   alert(res);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("AJAX call failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
  });
```

any help appreciated !

Comment: You define the `"/logged"` route, but you call `"user_form/logged"`, it just doesn't match. You don't match any route, therefore you get a 500.

Comment: but on the app.use I defined the basic path as user_form, should it recognize the full path as "user_form/logged ?

Comment: Ah right, that should be `"/user_form/logged"` then. You forgot the starting `/`

Comment: add it but still getting the error

Comment: I also tried using this method in the client side **$.get("/user_form/logged", function (data) {
    if(data){
        console.log(data);
        logged = data;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});
//--**

Comment: can you try to console.log(req.session) in GET request route?

Comment: it doesn't get inside the route so nothing in there gets executed